# Azure Detection with Custom Vision and OCR text detection

Tags: ocr, azure-cognitive-services

i'm studying the Azure Custom Vision service for object detection, but I would like also to extrapolate text information within a tagged image zone.
Is it possible with Custom Vision?
If not, is it in the service roadmap?
Thank you

Comment: You want to process OCR in the zone of the object detected by custom vision, right? In that case you can directly trim your image based on the bounding box of the object and then call the `OCR` method of Azure Computer Vision

Comment: Microsoft has a OCR service: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/.

It outputs bounding boxes together with the text.